# Find the Start Index and End Index of the same Element in a Matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to get the start index and end Index of the same repetitive Element in a matrix?
for example this Matrix:

[image: Matrix]

the result will be:

[image: Result]

zero is not considered

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: Are you only looking along columns or for the whole matrix?

Comment: yes it´s for the whole matrix!

Answer (score 0):

You can go this way (example for 1):

```
a = rem(find(A==1),5)
a(a==0)=5;
startidx = min(a)
endidx = max(a)
```

The same way change `A==1` to whatever you need and you'll get the result. You also can create a function with parameters `A, number_you_want_to_find`.
There are some ways to improve this code, for example instead `5` use `size(A,1)` and maybe there is some way to replace all this code with one line, but this works too!

Hope, it was helpful!